# What is causing the deadlock?

Tags: c#, winforms, task, deadlock, .net-4.8

I know this is not using the proper form, but can someone tell me why the first code snippet works and the 2nd causes a deadlock?

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     textBox1.Text = DownloadStringV3("https://www.google.com");
}

public string DownloadStringV3(String url) 
{ 
      var resp = new HttpClient().GetAsync(url).Result;
      return resp.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
}
```

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     textBox1.Text = DownloadStringV3("https://www.google.com").Result;
}

public async Task<string> DownloadStringV3(String url) 
{ 
     var resp = await new HttpClient().GetAsync(url);
     return await resp.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
}
```

Different synchronization contexts? This is using .NET 4.8

Comment: use `async`/`await`. Don't use `.Result` in UI-based applications. Change the 2nd one to `private async void button1_Click(...){textBox1.Text = await ...`.

Comment: Did you read the first line?  I know what the correct form is.   What I want to know what the underlying reason for the difference.

Comment: Windows Forms supports [async event handlers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13922371/using-the-new-async-await-pattern-with-windows-forms-designer-in-visual-studio-2), please rewrite your code to reflect that and remove all forced `.Result`s.

Comment: Start by reading [this doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2013/march/async-await-best-practices-in-asynchronous-programming).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every time you `await` something, you say, I am temporary done here, give some other thread a chance to execute and then continue from here, when the async task is completed.

So in your case `await new HttpClient().GetAsync(url)` switches the the ui thread and waiting for `DownloadStringV3("https://www.google.com").Result` be done, which will never be the case, because we do never execute `return await resp.Content.ReadAsStringAsync()`.

Thats why you should do async all the way to the root and never call `Result`.

The first code works, because you block on the UI thread and don't try to switch to another thread, while waiting for it.

To make the second one working you need to:

```
private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     // make with try catch sure, you catch any error, async void is special. Better is async Task
     textBox1.Text = await DownloadStringV3("https://www.google.com");
}

public async Task<string> DownloadStringV3(String url) 
{ 
     var resp = await new HttpClient().GetAsync(url);
     return await resp.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response.  You are right, in the 2nd example, the first awaited call (GetAsync) allows the UI thread to transfer to button1_click which then blocks on .Result.    When the GetAsync method finishes, the continuation is blocked forever waiting for the UI thread to become free.

In the first example, control never leaves DownloadString3 until all work is completed.  This article was helpful https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html

Comment: This article also has details that could be helpful to others in understanding the ultimate cause of the deadlock.  
https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/configureawait-faq/